# How to create/draw this text box shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to make this kind of shape in photoshop? text split in slash and add color.

[image: text box shape split with slash]

I know its basic stuff but I have no idea. Last time PS used was like 4 years back. Please help.. I am using Photoshop CC. Thank you.

EDIT : LOL [image: Thank You!]

Answer (score 4):

Use the **Shape Tools** to draw a rounded rectangle.

Use the **Pen Tool** and it's options to square-off one end.

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to move an anchor on the square end so it's at an angle.

Duplicate and flip the shape layer you have and use the **Direct Selection Tool** to alter the angle.

Duplicate the shape layer again, square off the other side, and adjust its angle.

[image]

You can then just double-click the layers to change their colors.

(I'd do a better job of making certain the angles were all the same and equidistant if I were *actually* going to use this.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you usually use InDesign? Photoshop's text boxes are very different. You have to create the shape you want, then just use text as a separate object. I'm sure there is a much easier way, but this is how I would do it!

*p.s. I have to add that it drives me insane that the separating lines aren't the same angle!*

1. Select the **Rounded Rectangle** object and create a rectangle.
   [image]
2. To adjust the roundness of the corners, adjust the px to around 40-something in the properties (default is usually around 10px). This is also where you can double-click the color and select your desired color. 
   [image]
3. Create 2 white lines to seperate the sections. The **Line** tool is in the same location as the Rounded Rectangle - just right click the shape, and you'll see "line" as an option. Again, make the color white in the properties box and adjust the angle. "Ctrl+T" will allow you to transform. Once you have the right size/color, duplicate the object by right clicking the layer and **Duplicate Layer** 
   [image]
   [image]
4. Now highlight all three layers (rounded rectangle, shape 1, shape 1 copy) & **Rasterize**

[image]

5. While still highlighted, merge the layers (right click, **Merge Layers**).
6. Select the **Paint Bucket** tool. Press "alt" & click desired color to make it that color, or select new color. click inside the box you wish to paint. repeat with the blue. 
   [image]
7. Now, just use the text tool to write over each object.

I hope that helps some, and if someone has a better way, please post!

Answer (score 0):

Make the object with the shape tool. Either use the pen tool or make a new shape and then skew it (Edit -> Transform -> Skew) to get the angled look and then apply it as a clipping mask over the first shape. Apply a stroke using a layer effect.